# How to extract blood vein from following images using python and open?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to enhance blood vein part in forearm image shown below.[image]

After grayscale conversion I got following image.
[image]

Then I followed histogram equalization and got better result as shown below
[image]

Based on the histogram equalized image, I need to enhance blood vein part in original image. For that purpose first I need to extract blood vein from histogram equalized image, but I am not getting any result. Can anyone suggest proper method to enhance blood vein in original infrared image. ?? I am using python+OpenCV for image processing

Area of interest to extract is shown below
[image]

Comment: For those of us who are not neuro-physio-venal-surgeon-thingies, could you maybe mark on a separate picture which bits you are hoping to locate please?

Comment: I would try a gabor filter with long masks.

Comment: There exists the so called *Multiscale vessel enhancement filtering* approach by Frangi et. al. [Sorry, I can't find a free resource][1].

I did a C++ implementation of this filter some time ago, I'll give it a try on that one.


  [1]: http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0056195

Comment: @MarkSetchell : I have added area of interest to enhance.

Comment: @FiReTiTi: is gabour transform is available in OpenCv + Python??

Comment: @s1h: I will try your suggestions..thank you

Comment: I am pretty sure they are, but as I don't use either of them, I am not certain.